# Extract name a numerics values from data frame in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

Im want obtain the name and number not .jpg text.
Im try with different regular expression like `p`.

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- structure(list(LEAF = c("ARG    1.jpg", "ARG    2.jpg", "ARG    3.jpg", 
      "ARG    4.jpg", "ARG   16.jpg", "ARG   19.jpg", "ARG   23.jpg", 
      "ARG   29.jpg", "ARG   31.jpg", "ARG   32.jpg", "ARG   35.jpg", 
      "ARG   40.jpg", "ARG   44.jpg", "ARG   48.jpg", "ARG   49.jpg", 
      "ARG   50.jpg", "ARG   52.jpg", "ARG   54.jpg", "ARG   62.jpg", 
      "ARG   70.jpg")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
      "tbl", "data.frame"))

d %>% 
  mutate(p = str_extract(LEAF, "\\b[A-Z]{3}"),
    p2= str_extract(LEAF,  '.[0−9]'),
    p3= str_extract(LEAF,  '[0−9]'),
    p4= str_extract(LEAF,  '[0−9]*$'))

LEAF            p     p2    p3    p4
<chr>         <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 ARG    1.jpg ARG   NA    NA    ""
2 ARG    2.jpg ARG   NA    NA    ""
3 ARG    3.jpg ARG   NA    NA    ""
4 ARG    4.jpg ARG   NA    NA    ""
5 ARG   16.jpg ARG   NA    NA    ""
6 ARG   19.jpg ARG   19    9     ""
7 ARG   23.jpg ARG   NA    NA    ""
8 ARG   29.jpg ARG   29    9     ""
9 ARG   31.jpg ARG   NA    NA    ""
10 ARG   32.jpg ARG   NA    NA    ""
11 ARG   35.jpg ARG   NA    NA    ""
12 ARG   40.jpg ARG   40    0     ""
13 ARG   44.jpg ARG   NA    NA    ""
14 ARG   48.jpg ARG   NA    NA    ""
15 ARG   49.jpg ARG   49    9     ""
16 ARG   50.jpg ARG   50    0     ""
17 ARG   52.jpg ARG   NA    NA    ""
18 ARG   54.jpg ARG   NA    NA    ""
19 ARG   62.jpg ARG   NA    NA    ""
20 ARG   70.jpg ARG   70    0     ""
```

Im need the only the complete name, like this:

Because I need compare with other DF with this names.

```
  LEAF            |      p      |
 -----------------|-------------|
 1 ARG     1.jpg  |  ARG     1  |
 2 ARG     2.jpg  |  ARG     2  |
10 ARG    32.jpg  |  ARG    32  |
```

Comment: I think `str_remove` is allows you to accomplish your task a little easier since you just have to remove the .jpg part. In base R you can use `gsub` like `d$p <- gsub("\\.jpg" ,"", d$LEAF)`

Comment: Yes!, Im see the questions in different form but with `str_remove` is more fast. Tnks! Was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
d %>% 
  mutate(
    p = str_extract(LEAF,".*(?=\\.jpg)")
  )
```